# MySQL query duplicates from 2 columns

Tags: mysql, query, mysql-workbench

I need to query duplicates in a table from 2 columns (agents_name) and (estates_name) based off the (display_name) column.

I tried the following:

```
SELECT id, display_name, author_table.agents_name, author_table.estates_name, agents_name, estates_name
FROM author_table

INNER JOIN(
SELECT agents_name and estates_name
FROM author_table
GROUP BY agents_name and estates_name
HAVING COUNT(agents_name) >1 and COUNT(estates_name)>1
)temp ON author_table.agents_name and author_table.estates_name = temp.estates_name;
```

The last 'sentence' should create a temporary table but I'm getting Error Code: 1054, unknown column temp.estates_name

Comment: `SELECT agents_name and estates_name` -- you must have meant `SELECT agents_name, estates_name`

Comment: @mustaccio I just tried it with agents_name, estates_name but now I'm getting a different error: 1052 'agents_name' in field list is ambiguous.

Comment: *duplicates in a table from 2 columns (agents_name) and (estates_name)* Does it must be a pair duplicate, or each separate column must be a duplicate (maybe in different records)?

Comment: `COUNT(x)` is the number of rows _rows_ have `x` being _non-null_; `COUNT(DISTINCT x)` is the number of different values of `x`; `SUM(x=5)` is the number of rows where `x=5`.  Which do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use aliases for your table especially when you self join

```
SELECT a1.id, a1.display_name, a1.agents_name, a1.estates_name, t.agents_name, t.estates_name
FROM author_table a1
INNER JOIN(
SELECT agents_name.lestates_name
FROM author_table
GROUP BY agents_name and estates_name
HAVING COUNT(agents_name) >1 AND COUNT(estates_name)>1
)temp t ON a1.agents_name = t.agents_name AND a1.estates_name = t.estates_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need (duplicated pair)

```
SELECT author_table.*
FROM author_table
NATURAL JOIN ( SELECT agents_name, estates_name
               FROM author_table
               GROUP BY agents_name, estates_name
               HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ) temp;
```

?

---

Or, maybe, you need this (separate duplicates)

```
SELECT author_table.*
FROM author_table
NATURAL JOIN ( SELECT agents_name
               FROM author_table
               GROUP BY agents_name
               HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ) temp1
NATURAL JOIN ( SELECT estates_name
               FROM author_table
               GROUP BY estates_name
               HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ) temp2;
```

?